# Trying to click a button with Selenium Webdriver using Cucumber-JS

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I tried the whole day to press a button in a Automated test using a different selectors (id, class and href) but I could't. With ID is more easier, but I practice with youtube and after the first click (on the hamburguer menu) I could't press on any tab after that (History, Subscriptions, Library, etc..)

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { expect, assert } = require('chai');

let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

Given('Youtube', {timeout: 2 * 5000}, async function () {
  await driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ES&hl=es');
});

When('Library', {timeout: 2 * 5000}, async function () {
  await  driver.findElement(By.id("guide-icon")).click();
});

When('Notice', {timeout: 2 * 5000}, async function () {
  await  driver.findElement(By.css("style-scope ytd-guide-entry-renderer")).click();
});
```

Also tried with Xpath (I need to locate specific parts of the web, and I have multiple classes with same values).

```
When('Notice', {timeout: 2 * 5000}, async function () {
  await  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/feed/history']")).click();
});
```

The feature file is OK.

I Receive this message everytime when I run the test

```
 NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"style-scope ytd-guide-entry-renderer"}
         (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I am writing selenium using javascript

But I can tell you about the problem

Because you may enter a certain level after clicking (iframe...)

So there is a solution

Switch the leaves again to the outermost layer

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());//javascript
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! :) How can I know in which frame the page is (in fact, is a SideBar)

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute of the element is a class, it should be:

```
.style-scope.ytd-guide-entry-renderer
```

You can't just put the attribute value. You need to specify a bit more.